# Django FileSystemStorage. Access to files saved on External Hard Drive

Tags: django, local-storage, storage, filepath

I have set my FileSystemStorage in location='E:/'. Its an external Hard Drive. I'am working in local with a simple app in Django.

It's working when I upload files. But I can't access from templates to files after that. Using the same path.

My model:

> fs= FileSystemStorage(location='E:/repositorio/')
>
> pdf_files = models.FileField(storage=fs, blank=False, null=False)

Comment: What is the output in your HTML when you render `pdf_files.path` and `pdf_files.url` in the template?

Comment: @MattRowbum , thanks for responding. Using {{ repositorio.pdf_files.path }} I get E:\repositorio\DJANGO_guide.pdf .      Another test:   <iframe src="E:/repositorio/DJANGO_guide.pdf"> doesn't works. But using </iframe>
<iframe src="{% static 'pdf/DJANGO_guide.pdf' %}"></iframe> and saving file in both path it works.

Comment: The result of `{{ repositorio.pdf_files.path }}` looks good. I'm a bit confused by the rest of your reply. Does that mean you have fixed the problem?

Comment: No @MattRowbum , sorry. I was trying to show that the problem is when files are outside Django's environment.

Comment: OK. If using `{% static 'pdf/DJANGO_guide.pdf' %}` in the template works for you, what does it output in the HTML?

Comment: @MattRowbum For example, if I use:**<iframe src="{{ repositorio.pdf_files.path }}">**  or  **<iframe src="E:/repositorio/{{ repositorio.pdf_files.name}}">** it doesn't works. Could it be a restriction of Django Server?

Comment: Can you confirm that `<iframe src="{% static 'pdf/DJANGO_guide.pdf' %}"></iframe>` does work? If so, can you look into the HTML source in your browser and tell me: `<iframe src="WHAT IS HERE?"></iframe>`.